# How to RegisterPostBackControl on every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

This worked for me in a normal .aspx page but not working in .ascx file.
I am trying to register post back for link button inside GridView which are inside update panel.

Comment: Show the code, what you are trying.